# Fourier transform help and mean filter

Tags: image-processing, filtering, fft

In image processing, if f(m,n) represent the image then MEAN filtering with a convolution mask h(m,n) will be represented by `g(m,n)=f(m,n) * h(m,n).` Now, here lies the confusion.

There is a question which asks that there is be a filter whose output at (x,y) is defined as the average of the four immediate neigbours of (x,y) but the pixel at (x,y) is not used. The question is: what is the kind / nature of the filter and what should be the MTF of this filter?

The mask/kernel for 3x3 mean filter is `h(m,n) = 1/9 [1 1 1;1 1 1; 1 1 1]` and output `g(m,n) = 1/9 x [f(m-1,n-1)+f(m-1,n)+f(m-1,n+1)+f(m,n-1) + f(m,n) +f(m,n+1) + f(m+!,n-1) +f(m+1,n) +f(m+1,n+1) ]` . The Center pixel at `x,y` is being considered !!

1. So, what is the correct way to construct for any kind of mean filter and will be h(m,n) (kernel) for the 3x3 mean filter and the 4 connected filter?
2. What is the fourier transform of h(m,n)?
3. How to decide if H(u,v), the fourier transform, is resulting into a high pass or low pass filter?

Answer (score 2):

There is no single "mean filter" - it's just a class of filters where you take the mean of a number of points. You can have a mean filter which takes the average of 4 adjacent points:

```
  0 1 0
  1 0 1
  0 1 0
```

or a 3x3 mean filter:

```
  1 1 1
  1 1 1
  1 1 1
```

or a 5x5 mean filter:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

or any kernel geometry you like.

In general though a mean filter is a (not very good) low pass filter. The advantage of a mean filter is low computational complexity (no coefficient multiplies), but unless your performance requirements are very high then there are much better low pass filters which should be considered.

The Fourier Transform of any given mean filter is fairly easy to calculate once you know the exact kernel geometry you want to use, and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I really do not understand how to find out the fourier transform for this masks as integral of h exp[-2pi(ux+vy)] dx dy so what will be the values that area replaced for h(m,n)? Could you kindly show an example?

Comment: The values will just be 1 or 0 depending on your mean filter geometry. If you don't know how to calculate the FT of a filter kernel then that probably needs to be a separate question, and belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com (as does the original question above).